# Failed to install wikidata-query-rdf / Blazegraph

Tags: java, git, maven, jar, wikidata

I am trying to install wikidata-query-rdf (https://github.com/wikimedia/wikidata-query-rdf) and there is a failure with Blazegraph :

```
git clone https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/wikidata/query/rdf wikidata-query-rdf
cd wikidata-query-rdf
sudo mvn install
```

I first get this kind of warning : 
[WARNING] The POM for com.blazegraph:bigdata-cache:jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available

And then :

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] parent ............................................. SUCCESS [  6.246 s]
[INFO] Shared code ........................................ SUCCESS [ 19.727 s]
[INFO] Wikidata Query RDF Testing Tools ................... SUCCESS [  9.955 s]
[INFO] Blazegraph extension to improve performance for Wikibase FAILURE [ 16.945 s]
[INFO] Blazegraph Service Package ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Wikidata Query RDF Tools ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Wikibase RDF Query Service ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 54.513 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-12-19T10:58:12+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 58M/420M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------


[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project blazegraph: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.wikidata.query.rdf:blazegraph:jar:0.3.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.blazegraph:bigdata-cache:jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT, com.blazegraph:bigdata-client:jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT, com.blazegraph:bigdata-common-util:jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT, com.blazegraph:bigdata-core:jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT, com.blazegraph:bigdata-util:jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT, com.blazegraph:ctc-striterators:jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.blazegraph:bigdata-cache:jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT in wmf.mirrored (http://archiva.wikimedia.org/repository/mirrored)
```

Comment: The answer is quite clear, or not? Some dependencies can't be found by Maven. You can see that it is looking in a repository where only releases but no SNAPSHOTS are available: https://archiva.wikimedia.org/repository/mirrored/com/blazegraph/bigdata-core/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some dependencies can't be found by Maven. You can see that it is looking in a repository where only releases but no SNAPSHOTS are available.

You should add the SNAPSHOT repository to the parent `pom.xml` file:

```
<repositories>
       ....
  <repository>
            <id>wmf.snapshots</id>
            <url>https://archiva.wikimedia.org/repository/snapshots</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

Or alternatively, change the Blazegraph dependency version property to latest release version:

```
<properties>
        <blazegraph.version>2.1.4</blazegraph.version>
        ...
</properties>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! What works also for me was to download an older version : https://github.com/wikimedia/wikidata-query-rdf/archive/0.2.1.zip