# Failed to execute goal on project blazegraph-service:

Tags: java, git, maven, wikidata, wikidata-api

I am trying to install wikidata-query-rdf according to this [link](https://github.com/wikimedia/wikidata-query-rdf/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md)

```
git clone  --recurse-submodules https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/wikidata/query/rdf wikidata-query-rdf
cd wikidata-query-rdf
mvn package
```

I've fixed error with maven following [this](https://github.com/nahsra/antisamy/issues/29) instructions, i.e

```
<configuration>
  <failOnError>false</failOnError>
</configuration>
```

Then I executed the following command once more

```
mvn package
```

and get this error

```
Failed to execute goal on project blazegraph-service: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.wikidata.query.rdf:blazegraph-service:war:0.3.3-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact com.blazegraph:bigdata-war:war:2.1.5-wmf.10 from/to wmf.releases (https://archiva.wikimedia.org/repository/releases): GET request of: com/blazegraph/bigdata-war/2.1.5-wmf.10/bigdata-war-2.1.5-wmf.10.war from wmf.releases failed:Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 56510112; received: 5897952
```

I've only found this solution ([Failed to install wikidata-query-rdf / Blazegraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47885637/failed-to-install-wikidata-query-rdf-blazegraph)) but all the errors mentioned there are already fixed in my files.

Comment: works for me as expected without doing anything. Just cloned the repo and did `mvn package` - you should check your network or just simply rerun the thing. Maven repos might have been offline when you tried it